# Nested Paste Statement in R

Tags: r, string, nested

This is one of those "There's got to be a better way!" things. I have a nested paste statement, which I will post below for context. I need to print a statement that says that "`group x` beat the following groups in a contest of `type y`: `group a, group b, ...group so and so`, where the "code" sections refer to different variables that are determined by other aspects of the function. The way I have it now is in several different paste statements nested together, five of them to be exact. Any ideas on how to make this less... messy? Here is the original code:

```
paste(paste(paste(paste(un[j], "beat out the following groups:"), paste(un[t],collapse=", ")), "in"), n[i])
```

Comment: `paste` can take multiple values. I only really see the need for two `paste`s (one to paste it all together and the other to collapse the groups that were beat out)

Comment: I think I was having problems with there not being a "collapse", but now I feel like an idiot for not thinking of this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `sprintf` for most of this:

```
un <- letters
paste(paste(paste(paste(un[1], "beat out the following groups:"), paste(un[2:10],collapse=", ")), "in"), un[11])

#...versus:
sprintf("%s beat out the following groups: %s in %s",un[1],paste(un[2:10],collapse = ", "),un[11])
```

Stylistically, I would probably even end up doing this in two lines to make it more readable:

```
grps <- paste(un[2:10], collapse = ", ")
sprintf("%s beat out the following groups: %s in %s",un[1],grps,un[11])
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you. I'm going to run some tests to see if it's faster than the one proposed above.